# WebRTC Native C++ examples: Difference between the relay server and turn server

Tags: c++, webrtc

I want to know the differences in use of these two examples as it both seem to relay a connection:

https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/master/examples/relayserver/relayserver_main.cc

https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/master/examples/turnserver/turnserver_main.cc

I'm already using turn server for browser to browser connections and I know, for example, that media servers like Kurento relays peer connections in order to save the user's bandwidth when connecting to multiple peers. Is the WebRTC Native relay server example the same as Kurento, (I mean, the concept)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, the relay-server is a very old version of google's TURN variant dating from before TURN became a standard.